# Vote to close dialog does not handle links to answers

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, hyperlinks, broken-links

These URLs work in a *vote to close » duplicate* dialog:

- `http://superuser.com/questions/231273/what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for`
- `http://superuser.com/questions/231273/what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for/233284#233284`
- `http://superuser.com/q/231273/22317`

This one doesn't:

- `http://superuser.com/a/233284/22317`

While this URL is redirected to the second URL in the first list when navigated to, it does not contain the question ID, only the answer ID. This is a technical detail that should not impact the user. It does, unfortunately:

> [image]

Comment: This is a feature-request, not a bug.  It clearly says "which **other question**?", and "please enter a **question** url".

Comment: @NickCraver OK. Just thought so because the *redirected* answer URL worked, since redirection adds the question ID. From a user POV, pre/post redirect shouldn't make a difference.